# How to get a json field by name using Spring WebClient?

Tags: json, spring, response, webclient, project-reactor

I have the following JSON Response:

```
{
    "Count": 1,
    "Products": [
        {
            "ProductID": 3423
        },
        {
            "ProductID": 4321
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to return a List of "Product" from the Products array using WebClient without having to create a separate Dto class with the field 'ArrayList products'

I used something like this

```
        webClient.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .path(URI_PRODUCTS)
                .build())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Product.class)
                .collectList();
```

It retrieves a List with one Product in it but all the values null. I am able to get it to work with a DTO response such as

```
...retrieve().bodyToMono(ProductResponse.class).block();
```

Where the ProductResponse has the List of Products in it. But I am trying to avoid having to create the extra class. Is there a way to pull the field similar to using jsonPath (similar to WebTestClient)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after `retrieve()` you can always `.map` your result to corresponding type. With the help of `JsonNode` `path()` instance method you can do it similar to `WebTestClient` `jsonPath()`

```
webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                .path(URI_PRODUCTS)
                .build())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
            .map(s-> s.path("Products"))
            .map(s->{
                try {
                    return mapper.readValue(s.traverse(), new TypeReference<List<Product>>() {} );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return new ArrayList<Product>();
                }
            })
            .block();
```

Comment: I ended up creating a 'ProductDto', but I used your method and it worked for another issue I was having! Thank you!

Comment: @Nikolay Great answer and it works for me but I have a small detail question: Why did you opt for 's' as the local variable name in your lambdas? I'm curious what it's short for

Comment: @Ghoti and Chips that 's' is representing JsonNode.

Comment: @AjayKumar I'm aware what it's representing, I was wondering out of curiousity why he chose "s", what's it an abbreviation for